# How to process credit card from a RoR application ? Stripe is not available in my country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, credit-card, payment-processing, stripe-payments

I wasn't sure where to ask this so decided to ask at SO, I have built an RoR app and want to process credit card of clients (monthly subscription), how can I do it (stripe is not available in my country) ?

I meant what options I have (I can search online documentation for the integration part but need to know the options first)

Comment: It would probably help us if you told us which country you are in ;)

Answer (score 2):

Some useful links:

Tutorial: [Credit Card Processing with Ruby on Rails](http://larsgebhardt.de/credit-card-processing-with-ruby-on-rails/)

Ruby Gem: [Credit Card Validator](https://github.com/tobias/credit_card_validator)

Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe?view=asciicast

Comment: thanks, actually I was looking for name of services which I can use, I am using paypal but need a better option

Answer (score 1):

Use PayPal payment gateway.it provides lots of functionalities or you can use authorize.net , or braintree for monthly subscription

Comment: Thanks Lalit, actually I was looking for name of services which I can use, I am using paypal but need a better option

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for subscription model, either use braintree recurring payments or some other providers like Zuora or ChargeBee.

If it is a simple system, stick with braintree, charges are low. For extra stuff like proration and mailing look at Zuora or ChargeBee